# Show button when 2 inputs are full and valid in react native

Tags: reactjs, native

****I have a react native page app with 2 inputs. ****

*I want to show the "submit" button once all of the 2 fields have a value.*

(button is invisible until the 2 input fields have value)

this is my page code :

```
class Page3 extends Component {
    
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.question1Stack}>
            <Text style={styles.question1}>Question1</Text>
            <ImageBackground
              source={require("./assets/undraw_Friends_online_re_r7pq.png")}
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={styles.image}
              imageStyle={styles.image_imageStyle}
            >
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2')}}>
              <Icon name="chevron-left" style={styles.icon1}></Icon>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity
        title="submit"
        
          onPress={() => {
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Page4');
          }}>
               <Text   style={styles.next}>
         Next 
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
          <MaterialHelperTextBox
            style={styles.materialHelperTextBox}
          ></MaterialHelperTextBox>
          <MaterialHelperTextBox1
            style={styles.materialHelperTextBox1}
          ></MaterialHelperTextBox1>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

these are my input fields :

```
<MaterialHelperTextBox
            style={styles.materialHelperTextBox}
          ></MaterialHelperTextBox>
          <MaterialHelperTextBox1
            style={styles.materialHelperTextBox1}
          ></MaterialHelperTextBox1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you most define to two state for two `TextInput` , than set `TextInput` value in `onChangeText` check value is not null and valid , set `true` states for check, I don't know you use `MaterialHelperTextBox1` by witch component but code maybe like this:

```
class Page3 extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        checkInput1:false,
        checkInput2:false,
        inputValue1:'',
        inputValue2:'',
        };
    };
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.question1Stack}>
            <Text style={styles.question1}>Question1</Text>
            <ImageBackground
              source={require("./assets/undraw_Friends_online_re_r7pq.png")}
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={styles.image}
              imageStyle={styles.image_imageStyle}
            >
              {checkInput1 && checkInput2 ?
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
              {this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2')}}>
              <Icon name="chevron-left" style={styles.icon1}></Icon>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            :
            null
            }
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity
        title="submit"
        
          onPress={() => {
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Page4');
          }}>
               <Text   style={styles.next}>
         Next 
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
          <MaterialHelperTextBox
            style={styles.materialHelperTextBox}
            onChangeText={value => {this.setstate({inputValue1:value}); 
             _checkInputIsValid1();}}
            defaultValue={this.state.inputValue1}
          ></MaterialHelperTextBox>
          <MaterialHelperTextBox1
            style={styles.materialHelperTextBox1}
              onChangeText={value => {this.setstate({inputValue2:value}); 
             _checkInputIsValid2();}}
            defaultValue={this.state.inputValue1}
          ></MaterialHelperTextBox1>
        </View>
      );
    }
}

_checkInputIsValid1(){
//check your rules for input1 there if true set state checkInput1 as true
}
_checkInputIsValid2(){
//check your rules for input2 there if true set state checkInput2 as true
}
```